# query in hibernate returns one row while in oracle returns multiple row

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

My sql query below returns a single row in hibernate while the same query geting printed in console returns the desired output.
I trie with another query it was giving a desired result.. I believe there is a bug in hibernate
My code is below

```
sql="select root_cause_category,count(root_cause_category) cnt from zrobot_inc_resolution_details where lower(inc_state)='closed' and\r\n" + 
                    "replace(to_char(resolved_at,'Month-yyyy'),' ','')='"+selDate+"'\r\n" + 
                    condition1+" and template_validated='Y' and is_compliant='Y' group by root_cause_category \r\n" + 
                    "order by cnt";
                    
                    query=session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                    ob=(ArrayList<Object[]>) query.list();
```

Comment: So `ob.size()` is 1? Do you have debug logs and show_sql enabled? Can you post them?

Comment: yes size is 1 . show_sql is enabled

Comment: What is the hibernate logs looking like?

Comment: Happening because of this   "replace(to_char(resolved_at,'Month-yyyy'),' ','')='"+selDate+"'\r\n". Resolved_at is timestamp and seldate is 'Jul-2021'.
Whenever I comment it it works but on adding it errors out. I am not sure of the solutuion